# 301 Redirection using .htaccess not working for multiple parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I actually want to redirect my old website url to new website url.

I have made 1 redirect working properly

for example

```
http://www.abc-old.com/test to http://www.abc-new.com/test123
```

but problem is while i have multiple slug or parameters it won't work for me

like

i want to redirect

```
http://www.abc-old.com/test1/test2 to http://www.abc-new.com/test1
```

but it is redirecting like

```
 http://www.abc-old.com/test1/test2 to http://www.abc-new.com/test1/test2
```

below is my code for same

```
Redirect 301 /test1/test2 http://www.abc-new.com/test1
```

Please help me to sort out this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your .htaccess file  looks like / or the httpd.conf contains this it should work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /test1/test2 http://www.abc-new.com/test1
```

Maybe this could be interesting.

http://www.internetmarketingninjas.com/blog/search-engine-optimization/301-redirects/

Comment: not working Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /kaffemaskiner/office-coffee http://coffee-break-new.no/kaffemaskiner

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in old host's root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "/test1/test2(/.*)?$ http://www.abc-new.com/test1$1
```

Comment: These type of comments never help. What URL did you try? Did it cause 404? Are there existing rules? If yes post them in question.

Comment: Glad to know it worked, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hie Some how i solved it but still confuse why this thing happned ?

for example I have 3 URL

```
http://www.old.com/test1/
http://www.old.com/test1/test2
http://www.old.com/test1/test2/test3
```

I have created 301 redirects in .htaccess like

```
Redirect 301 /test1/ http://www.new.com/test1
Redirect 301 /test1/test2/ http://www.new.com/test2
Redirect 301 /test1/test2/test3 http://www.new.com/test3
```

in this case

while i was requesting

```
http://www.old.com/test1/ is redirected to http://www.new.com/test1
```

while

```
http://www.old.com/test1/test2 is redirected to http://www.new.com/test1/test2/
```

in this case while server execute .htaccess , instead of my second url redirection first was working and additional parameter passing test2 so it new redirect was http://www.new.com/test1/test2

I have write code like this

```
Redirect 301 /test1/test2/test3 http://www.new.com/test3
Redirect 301 /test1/test2/ http://www.new.com/test2
Redirect 301 /test1/ http://www.new.com/test1
```

and it started working. i really don't understand why my first code is not working, I have used wordpress CMS , is there any cofiguration required ?